# AutoParrallexBackGround not Working?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am trying to implement autoparrallexbackgrounf using andengine 2 for sample. But its not working for me. A still screen appears with player sprite still at centre. Here are my two classes.. can anybody help what i am doing wrong?

```
package com.example.movingbackground;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.WakeLockOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity
{
public Camera mCamera = null;
private static final int width = 480;
private static final int height = 800;
private GamePlay mScene = null;


public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() 
{
    mCamera  = new Camera(0, 0, width, height);
    EngineOptions eo = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), mCamera);
    eo.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
    return eo;
}

protected void onCreateResources() 
{
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    loadRes();
}

private void loadRes()
{
    mScene = new GamePlay(this);
}

protected Scene onCreateScene() 
{
    return mScene;
}

}
```

Scene Class goes like :

```
package com.example.movingbackground;

import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.AutoParallaxBackground;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.ParallaxBackground.ParallaxEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;

public class GamePlay extends Scene 
{
private MainActivity mCxt = null;
private Sprite background_1 = null;
private Sprite background_2 = null;
private Sprite background_3 = null;
private AutoParallaxBackground bg = null;
private Sprite player = null;

public GamePlay(MainActivity mCxt) 
{
    this.mCxt = mCxt;

    bg = new AutoParallaxBackground(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1f);
    background_1 = new Sprite(0, 0, getSpriteRegion(640, 1136, "bg.png"), this.mCxt.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    background_2 = new Sprite(0, 0, getSpriteRegion(640, 1136, "bg.png"), this.mCxt.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    background_3 = new Sprite(0, 0, getSpriteRegion(640, 1136, "bg.png"), this.mCxt.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    player = new Sprite(100, 100, getSpriteRegion(512, 512, "icon.png"), this.mCxt.getVertexBufferObjectManager())
    {
        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            player.setX(player.getX()+10);          
        }
    };

    attachChilds();
    setBackground(bg);
}

private void attachChilds()
{
    bg.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, background_1, 640, 1136));
    bg.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, background_2, 640, 1136));
    bg.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, background_3, 640, 1136));

    attachChild(player);
    this.mCxt.mCamera.setChaseEntity(player);
}

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    this.mCxt.mCamera.updateChaseEntity();  
}


private TextureRegion getSpriteRegion(int width, int height, String name)
{
    BitmapTextureAtlas atlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.mCxt.getTextureManager(), width, height, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    atlas.load();   
    return BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(atlas, this.mCxt.getAssets(), name , 0 , 0);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only worked with a Parllax Background in andengine right now, but I think the problem is, that you create all your ParallaxEntitys with 0.0f as parallaxFactor. (The first parameter is the parallaxFactor, isn't it?)

I'm not sure, but I think something like

```
bg.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(5.0f, background_1, 640, 1136));
bg.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(10.0f, background_2, 640, 1136));
bg.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(15.0f, background_3, 640, 1136));
```

should work.